# Why can I not alias a column in a view?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to create a view that provides all quarter starts from a date dimension. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW quarter_starts AS
SELECT min(day_number_in_epoch) AS day_num FROM date_dimension dd
GROUP BY dd.calendar_year_quarter;
```

And postgres gives the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot change name of view column "min" to "day_num"
```